# How to fix ENTER key in mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a large mysql table and I just noticed an issue when trying to query the database. It seems like the ENTER key was pressed when some columns were inserted. For example, I can perform the following search:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE color= 'red'");
```

Now, I may have 20 rows where the color is red but less are showing. When I use phpmyadmin to edit the lines not showing in the search results, I notice the color column says `red` but has a line break so that the cursor is on a line underneath the word "red". If I use the backspace key once to erase the line then save the row, it now appears in my query results.

My database is quite large, so I was wondering if there was any way to search the database where `color` has any "extra characters" on the end of the value, and remove those extra characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRIM only removes spaces by default. The following will remove the linebreak:

```
UPDATE table SET color = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM color)
```

Ref: [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: @zerkms I was about to undo my vote as you were going to remove the incorrect answer but you were too quick - sorry.